# convert PIL numpy 3d array to 2d luma values

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've loaded an image using:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
imag = Image.open("image.png")    
I = np.asarray(imag)
```

Where the shape of `I` is `(951, 1200, 3)`

But I would like to average each pixel roughly to it's luma values (`(r*g*b)/3`) to make the shape `(951, 1200, 1)`.

What is the proper numpy operator to do this?

Comment: `imag = Image.open("image.png").convert('L')` should be good enough?

Comment: What Mark said. And it'll give you a more accurate luminance than your unweighted mean will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest thing is to use Pillow's built-in conversion to Luminance as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load image and convert to luminance, and thence to Numpy array
imag = Image.open("image.png").convert('L')    
I = np.asarray(imag)
```

Comment: That’s the ticket! Thank you!

Comment: Excellent - glad it works for you. Good luck with your project, and remember to come back if you get stuck - questions (and answers) are free :-)

Comment: Haha! Thanks Mark!